# RTF Text To RichTextBlock in windows 8 XAML

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, rtf

i have to display RTF text direct into RichTextBlock of windows 8 XAML control is it possible and how ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to actually use a RichEditBox by calling myRichEditBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, yourRtf).
This post explains how to bind to the text: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=f9a83d4e-26e9-476b-8818-7ccdf91a2341

This post explains some of the background on why RichEditBox is so stronger than RichTextBlock: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/de958373-72a5-4987-97be-1f6549ee143e

Comment: Unfortunately RichEditBox does not support overflow so it appears to be no use for doing pagination for printing.